# Shell script to display the number of files which are copying from one directory to another

Tags: linux, shell, file-copying

I want to display the number of files which are copied from one directory to other while doing "CP"command. what could be the command to add to it.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to periodically display the number of links in the target directory?  Write a script to periodically poll the target directory that outputs the number of entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `cp` man-pages, there is the `-v` parameter, which shows what is being done. This can be processed as in following simple example:

Normal usage of `cp -v`:

```
Prompt$ cp -v .bash_history /dev/null
'.bash_history' -> '/dev/null'
```

Now, with some processing (counting):

```
Prompt$ cp -v .bash_history /dev/null | wc -l
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ mkdir a b
$ touch a/{1,2,3}
$ ls a
1  2  3
$ find a -type f -exec sh -c 'echo $# ; cp "$@" b/.' sh {} + 
3
$ ls b
1  2  3
```

If the number of files exceeds the the maximum argument length, the command prints the number of files copied per chunk:

```
$ touch a/{0..99999}
$ find a -type f -exec sh -c 'echo $# ; cp "$@" b/.' sh {} + 
17768
16380
16380
16380
16380
16380
332
$ find b -type f | wc -l
100000
```

The first chunk is a bit bigger, because the file names are shorter.

Comment: thanks @ceving, but the previous solution worked fine for me